# Calling AWS Lambda With Compressed Payload To Get Under 6M Request Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

As you may know AWS Lambdas have a hard request(and response) payload limit of 6M.  I’m calling a Java Lambda deployed on API Gateway via a REST API with a gzip Content-Encoding, but API Gateway decompresses the request and calls the lambda with the uncompressed payload, so making a gzip request through API Gateway doesn’t help with the request payload limit.  So if I want to increase my request payload limit, how should I make the REST call with a gzipped request body without the API Gateway decompressing it?  A couple options:

1. configure API Gateway to allow gzip Content-Encoding requests through as-is.  This is my preferred option, but I haven’t figured out if this is possible.  There’s a x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types option to treat certain media types as binary, but changing this doesn’t seem to affect the decompression of incoming requests.  Ditto with the minimumCompressionSize option.
2. Change the incoming request to be `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` instead of `Content-Type: application/json` and `Content-Encoding: gzip`, and the in the API if it receives that type we decompress it as gzip in the lambda.  This would probably work, but it’s a bit hacky to use the generic octet-stream for a covert gzip request here.

What do you all think about these options(or some other option I haven’t considered)?  And yes, I know if I make the request via an async process I can get around the request limit, but async doesn't work well for the application.

Comment: I think it's worth re-evaluating the need to send such a large payload. If it genuinely can't be reduced then consider options such as S3 as an intermediary.